# Are hashes and MACs vulnerable to bit-flipping attacks?

Tags: encryption, aes, private-key, diffie-hellman

Suppose there is an encrypted communication between A and B, through an **unsecure** medium, such that A and B shared a secret key with DH protocol.

If A sends an encrypted message and the hash/MAC/HMAC of this message to B, wouldn't it be easy for an eavesdropper to just intercept the hash/MAC/HMAC, change some bits in it, and send it to B?

B wouldn't be able to check the integrity of all messages sent by A and thus will destroy them everytime he gets a message from A, right?

B will then become non available ???

Thank you

Comment: Haven't you heard of the Avalanche Effect?

Comment: What I understand from the Avalanche Effect is that when you change a bit in the message, the whole hash changes. But what if the attacker changes bits in the encrypted hash, since the medium is unsecure? the receiver will no longer be able to decrypt it and check the integrity of the message??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you describe is just a very specific form of corrupting the data. If an attacker can corrupt the data, then of course the attacker can prevent A from speaking to B. The attacker could just drop the packets on the ground. That would also prevent A from speaking to B.

Any data corruption, not just modifying the HMAC, will cause this same situation. If I modify the authenticated stream, then the (unmodified) HMAC won't match and it will be discarded.

The point of an HMAC is to ensure integrity. It has nothing to do with availability. Any Man-in-the-Middle can always trivially destroy availability in any system as long as the connection goes through them. (If they can't, they're not a MitM.)